# Problems while reloading pickled sklearn pipeline. Countvector analyzer function not being imported

Tags: machine-learning, flask, scikit-learn, pickle, pipeline

I am trying to pickle my text classification model and reload into a flask application interface.

I have a specific function that I use as analyzer called as **split_into_lemmas**

```
def split_into_lemmas(message):
    message = unicode(message, 'utf8').lower()
    words = TextBlob(message).words
    # for each word, take its "base form" = lemma 
    return [word.lemma for word in words]

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas,ngram_range= (1, 3), encoding='utf8',stop_words =None)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', count_vect), ('tdif', tfidf_transformer), ('clf', best_svc)])

%%time
text_clf.fit(X=data['Condition'], y=data['condition_predict'])
```

I fit the model and save it by pickling it

```
_ = joblib.dump(text_clf, 'classification_pipeline.pkl')
```

**On the other hand**
When I try to reload the pipeline

```
import pandas as pd 
import pickle
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from textblob import TextBlob
from sklearn.externals import joblib

clf_pipeline = open('C:/Users/Falco/Desktop/directory/WRMD_paper/classification_pipeline.pkl','rb')
clf = joblib.load(clf_pipeline)
```

I get following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bb0859b3946a> in <module>()
      6 
      7 clf_pipeline = open('C:/Users/Falco/Desktop/directory/WRMD_paper/classification_pipeline.pkl','rb')
----> 8 clf = joblib.load(clf_pipeline)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.pyc in load(filename, mmap_mode)
    586         filename = getattr(fobj, 'name', '')
    587         with _read_fileobject(fobj, filename, mmap_mode) as fobj:
--> 588             obj = _unpickle(fobj)
    589     else:
    590         with open(filename, 'rb') as f:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.pyc in _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    524     obj = None
    525     try:
--> 526         obj = unpickler.load()
    527         if unpickler.compat_mode:
    528             warnings.warn("The file '%s' has been generated with a "

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.pyc in load(self)
    862             while 1:
    863                 key = read(1)
--> 864                 dispatch[key](self)
    865         except _Stop, stopinst:
    866             return stopinst.value

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.pyc in load_global(self)
   1094         module = self.readline()[:-1]
   1095         name = self.readline()[:-1]
-> 1096         klass = self.find_class(module, name)
   1097         self.append(klass)
   1098     dispatch[GLOBAL] = load_global

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.pyc in find_class(self, module, name)
   1130         __import__(module)
   1131         mod = sys.modules[module]
-> 1132         klass = getattr(mod, name)
   1133         return klass
   1134 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'split_into_lemmas'
```

When I redeclare the function in the notebook the model loads well and runs, but when I save the notebook as .py file and run it as flask app, it does not run and gives me the same error.

Can someone help me save the pipeline correctly so that I don't have to declare the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are reloading pickle you need to define split_into_lemmas as well..